# What does this line from Reverse Gravity mean?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e

The spell [Reverse Gravity](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=261) includes this section (emphasis mine):

> Once an object or creature reaches the top of the area, it floats, caught between the normal and reversed gravity. **The creature can move along the plane where the two forms of gravity meet.** Creatures that can levitate or fly can use those abilities to mitigate the effects of reverse gravity.

What does the bolded sentence mean? It sounds like you can 'walk' on the top of the effect, but that doesn't make a lot of sense to me (lacking traction) so I was wondering if that's the case (because magic) or if there is another interpretation that is more accurate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bolded text allows characters to move with the Stride action, despite not normally being allowed to do so.

The section on [movement types](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=396) says:

> Most characters and monsters have a speed statistic—also called land Speed—which indicates how quickly they can move across the ground.

So under normal circumstances your intuition would be correct: they couldn't Stride (or Step) because their speed doesn't apply here. Without a fly speed or some other effect, they would be stuck. The bolded text specifically says that creatures can move along this plane though, so they can.

Although I have no logical explanation for this, I ran it this way at my table and nothing bad happened. To the contrary, the players had interesting tactical options despite being stuck in the spell's area. They were able to maneuver to attack flying creatures, use ranged attacks to shoot "downward", and even run outside the spell's area, fall downward, and continue their turn.